# Linux - Remove line feed

Tags: linux, linefeed

Is there a way to use linux command to remove the LF's displayed below.
Each row should begin with string 'F|'. Unfortunate multiple rows in my Oracle db are stored with hex 0a LF which at spool causes linebreaks.

Thanks

```
$grep -nvB 1 '^F|' File.txt
4720156-F|29|204380|A|16060|Telephone Updated by DCA|99996319        ,
4720157:                                                        |manual|
--
6005453-F|29|121389|A|16060|Telephone Updated by DCA|96844599        ,
6005454:                                                        |new|
--
6354243-F|29|366910|A|16060|Telephone Updated by DCA|
6354244:                                                        |new|
--
13318314-F|29|397713|A|16060|Telephone Updated by DCA|97597079        ,
13318315:                                                       ,52094436|new|
--
13471591-F|29|17945|A|16060|Telephone Updated by DCA|47990248,94291610,
13471592:                                                       |new|
--
13471607-F|29|152501|A|16060|Telephone Updated by DCA|
13471608:                                                       ,90290027,38297606|new|
--
13944867-F|29|322564|A|16060|Telephone Updated by DCA|
13944868:                                                       |new|
User@db01.test processed$
```

Comment: Did you try `hexdump -c File.txt`? If (as I suspect) your lines end with `\r\n` and your rows contain only single linefeeds (`\n`) you could use `sed` or `perl` to remove `\n` and then replace single `\r` with `\r\n` to get the original line endings back

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the lines which do not begin with `F|` to be joined to the line before (which does). A solution with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^F|/{x;2,$p;be};x;G;s/\n//;h;:e;${g;p}' File.txt
```

- `/^F|/` If line begins with `F|`:

  - `x` Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces
  - `2,$p` If not the first line: print the (previously held) line
  - `be` Branch to label `e`
- Otherwise (line doesn't begin with `F|`):

  - `x` Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces
  - `G` Append hold space to pattern space (lines joined, but still LF embedded)
  - `s/\n//` Remove the LF
  - `h` Copy pattern space (joined line) to hold space
- `:e` Label `e` (both cases above get here):

  - `$` If the last line:
  - `g` Copy hold space to pattern space
  - `p` Print the (last) line